# Not getting data value from [object XMLDocument] after success Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, webmethod

I have created a `javascript` and a `WebMethod`. It works in IE but not in firefox and chrome

**MyWebMethod**

```
[WebMethod]
    public string Send(string name, string email, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage objMailMessage = default(MailMessage);
            objMailMessage = new MailMessage();
            objMailMessage.From = new MailAddress(email, name,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            objMailMessage.To.Add("feedback@abc.in");
            objMailMessage.Subject = "Feedback";
            objMailMessage.Body = "<b>Name :</b> " + name + "<br/><br/>";
            objMailMessage.Body += "<b>Email :</b> " + email + "<br/><br/>";
            objMailMessage.Body+=  "<b>Message :</b> "+message;
            objMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            objMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;

            CommonFunctions.CommonFunctions.SendEmailMessage(objMailMessage);
            return "success";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log.Error(ex);
            return "Fail";
        }
    }
```

**MYScript**

```
$.ajax({
                    datatype: 'text',
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: options.url,
                    data: { name: $(this_id_prefix + '#name').val(), email: $(this_id_prefix + '#email').val(), message: $(this_id_prefix + '#message').val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $(this_id_prefix + '#loading').css({ display: 'none' });
                        var xmlDoc = data;
                        var returnvalue = xmlDoc.childNodes(1).firstChild.nodeValue;
                        if (returnvalue == "success") {
                            $(this_id_prefix+'#callback').show().append(options.recievedMsg);

                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $(this_id_prefix + '.holder').show();
                                $(this_id_prefix + '#callback').hide().html('');
                            }, 2000);

                        if(options.hideOnSubmit == true) {
                            //hide the tab after successful submition if requested
                            $(this_id_prefix+'#contactForm').animate({dummy:1}, 2000).animate({"marginLeft": "-=450px"}, "slow");
                            $(this_id_prefix+'div#contactable_inner').animate({dummy:1}, 2000).animate({"marginLeft": "-=447px"}, "slow").animate({"marginLeft": "+=5px"}, "fast"); 
                            $(this_id_prefix+'#overlay').css({display: 'none'});    
                        }
                    } else {
                        $(this_id_prefix+'#callback').show().append(options.notRecievedMsg);
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $(this_id_prefix+'.holder').show();
                            $(this_id_prefix+'#callback').hide().html('');
                        },2000);
                    }
                },
                error:function(){
                    $(this_id_prefix+'#loading').css({display:'none'}); 
                    $(this_id_prefix+'#callback').show().append(options.notRecievedMsg);
                                    }
 });
```

I am not able to get return value from `webmethod` to `script`. In **Success** funcation I want to check that `if(data=="Success")` but here I am not able to check that. Is there anything wrong in script like datatype or any other issue?  Here `var returnvalue = xmlDoc.childNodes(1).firstChild.nodeValue;` is not working. It works locally fine but after publish to server it's not working. It return object xmldocument in **data**. It's not returing string. I have changed datatype to **text**

Comment: you're not checking the data you get into `error:`, start by looking there

Comment: ok my code is write? or something wrong in my code like datatype?

Comment: Are this javascript and ws hosted on the same server? If not _same-origin policy_ won't let you to make ajax call.

Comment: yes it is hosted on same server